# How to unit test a mapbox popup with jasmine testing?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox popup. I am using jasmine and I want to write a unit test for it.

So I have this function:

```
  selectCluster(event: MouseEvent, feature: any) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    this.selectedCluster = {geometry: feature.geometry, properties: feature.properties};
  }
```

and this is the template:

```
 <ng-template mglClusterPoint let-feature>
        <div class="marker-cluster" (click)="selectCluster($event, feature)">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faVideo" [styles]="{'stroke': 'black', 'color': 'black'}" size="lg" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faWifi" [styles]="{'stroke': 'black', 'color': 'black'}" size="lg" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
```

and this is my unit test:

```
 fit('Should prevent popup will be closing after popup is triggered', () => {
    const ev = new Event('MouseEvent');
    spyOn(ev, 'stopPropagation');   
    expect(ev.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But I get this error:

```
Expected spy stopPropagation to have been called.
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you should be testing like that.

```
 it('Should set selectedCluster when clicked', () => {
    spyOn(component,'selectCluster').and.callThrough();
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.marker-cluster')).nativeElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.selectCluster).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.selectedCluster).toBe('whatever you are expecting')
  });
```

To test `stopPropagation`, you should rather focus on the event which is being stopped by it. If your test checks that the event is not happening, you can be sure that `event.stopPropagation();` is doing its thing in the code.